# widget stops working after installing an app

Tags: android, android-appwidget, onclicklistener

It is my first app widget. And I have a problem.
When I set the widget on the device it is working ok, but then, when I'm installing another app from the market it stops. I'm pressing on it and nothing happens.

This is my `onUpdate`:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("appWidgetId", appWidgetId).commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(WidgetIntent.WIDGET_INTENT);
        intent.setClassName(WidgetIntent.class.getPackage().getName(),
                WidgetIntent.class.getName());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);
    }
```

I am catching the broadcast in another class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

I see an answer that said I should set the `onClickPendingIntent on the onRecive` too. But, I tried that and it is not working. Maybe I didn't know how to do it.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I just noticed that it works fine on android 2.3 but stops on 4.1, why is that so? What is the difference in 4.1 that makes it stop?